# sudo apt update fails for NVIDIA drivers on WSL

Tags: apt, nvidia

I know there are some other old topics similar to this but I couldn't find any solution from them. I was trying to install the Nvidia drivers and when I ran sudo apt update I got this error:

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/chronitis/jupyter/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I also can't reboot and get this error:

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
Failed to talk to init daemon.
```

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS and WSL2

Comment: You cannot use Linux NVIDIA drivers on WSL. Windows controls the hardware - you must use Windows drivers.

Comment: PPAs are 3rd party sources, so all security checks are on you. A quick look and I can see support for that PPA dried up in 2018, well before 2020-April or 20.04 so that alone is a reason not to add it, let alone an unmaintained 3rd party source code be a security risk... did you perform any checks, as being 3rd party; all these checks are on you.

Comment: What do you need the NVIDIA drivers for?  WSL is command line only and not intended to run a desktop environment or GUI applications.  See: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/faq#can-i-run-all-linux-apps-in-wsl -AND-  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gpu-compute

Comment: @guiverc So, there is no way for me to use this without taking security risk. What do you mean by saying perform any checks?

Comment: @Nmath I need it to use my GPU to be able to train deep learning models.

Comment: Security is your decision; how much risk are you willing to take (assuming your box is online; if it's offline its a moot point).  The PPA in question (https://launchpad.net/~chronitis/+archive/ubuntu/jupyter) on looking shows the releases it provided support for in the drop-down box (filter), and if you look at the dates when it was being actively supported; you'll note it was years ago. That isn't the page I viewed (I just opened the link in your paste and I didn't need to go further; but assessing a PPA before add; I look at who created it, are they trustworthy, maintaining it.. etc

Comment: @user535733 Yeah I realized that but Windows driver doesn't work either. Apparently, there is a driver for WSL users but it causes a black screen blinking issue.